# Netplan: How to give a specific NIC a specific name and IP Address

Tags: networking, ethernet, netplan

OK so here is the setup:
The DHCP server assigns specific MAC addresses their IPs. The machine in question has mutliple NICs and their interfaces are named eth0-5. BTW only one NIC is connected, the one with MAC address 00:30:18:08:03:f5.

The netplan config  looks as follows:

```
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f0
      optional: true
    eth1:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f1
      optional: true
    eth2:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f2
      optional: true
    eth3:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f3
      optional: true
    eth4:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f4
      optional: true
    eth5:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f5
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

Yet with each boot it is a different interface that gets the MAC and IP. Here's what ifconfig shows:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:30:18:08:03:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf160000-df17ffff

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:30:18:08:03:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf140000-df15ffff

eth2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:30:18:08:03:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf120000-df13ffff

eth3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:30:18:08:03:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf100000-df11ffff

eth4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.2.1.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.2.1.255
        ether 00:30:18:08:03:f5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 220  bytes 21996 (21.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 178  bytes 28347 (28.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf200000-df220000

eth5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:30:18:08:03:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdf000000-df01ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2868  bytes 204492 (204.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2868  bytes 204492 (204.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Please tell ma how I can make eth5 the interface with MAC 00:30:18:08:03:f5 and an assigned IP. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think setting the device name is a bit before netplan's involvement. Probably done by udev.

Comment: `/etc/udev/rules.d/20-persistent-net.rules` in my `20.10`

Comment: Use the netplan **set-name** to set user-friendly device names. See https://netplan.io/reference/ for more details. Also, I'm not sure what "dhcp-identifier: mac" does for this .yaml script. Also, your MAC address that show for eth4 and eth5 are flipped.

Comment: @heynnema: I tried using `set-name`, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287654/set-name-deactivates-the-interface). 

dhcp-identifier: mac asks the dhcp server to assign an IP based on the MAC address of the of the device, if the dhcp server has an appropriate record.

The flipping of the mac address is the issue. I want the interfaces and macs (and IPs if connected) to be as in the netplan config.

Comment: user slangasek is a netplan heavy, so you'll probably get an answer there. You might add a link back to this question so slangasek can understand the whole picture.

Comment: Thanks, great tip, but how do I contact a user directly?