# set-name deactivates the interface

Tags: networking, ethernet, netplan

I have the following interface config (just a snippet):

```
    eth5:
      match:
        macaddress: MAC ADDRESSS
      optional: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
```

and it works. Yet when I add the set-name property as below, the interface no longer shows up in `ifconfig`

```
    eth5:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:30:18:08:03:f5
      set-name: e5
      optional: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes

(Fifteen characters)